# How do I get data from the form inputs in a Freemarker template into a spring MVC controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am trying to receive simple text input from a form generated by a freemarker template.  The correct method is being invoked, but the model is empty, where I am expecting it to be populated.

I am working in the context of a pre-existing application, or I would have tossed this combination aside long ago and gone to a straight Spring MVC/JSP implementation.

I have been through every tutorial on the web, and many postings on this very topic in stackoverflow, and I am still failing to grasp something.  Whatever I am missing may be so elementary that no one bothers to post it.

The examples from within the application are not very helpful because they are constructed with sufficient indirection that I can't see how they work at all.

Freemarker template

```
<#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />
  <@spring.bind "model"/>

<form name="model" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="user" id="user" value="${model.user}"/>

  <input type="hidden" id="submission" name="submission"/>
  <input type="submit" name="test" id="test" value="Test" onclick="document.getElementById('submission').value = 'test'"/>
</form>
```

Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/config", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelMap postConfig(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {
    logger.debug("User name was {}", model.get("user")); // Why is model empty here?

    return model;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried annotating your class with (at)SessionAttributes("model"). This part of spring has caused me so much grief in the past. The problem is that there are so many different ways of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

In the end, I was unable to use the ModelMap as an input.  What I believe is the reason is that, while Spring has a million ways to accomplish any given task, the freemarker integration is not as robust as the jsp integration.

There is a little known but widely used feature of spring that resolves form elements to method parameters by name. Based on other people's comments I don't believe it is well documented. But, since it is core to the Groovy on Grails framework, I believe it is safe to consider it to be core to Spring.

The solution I finally used is this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/config", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelMap postConfig(String user) { 
    logger.debug("User name was {}", user); // Why is model empty here?

// ... snip ...
    model.put("user", user);
    return model;
}
```

Spring resolves form entities to the controller method parameters by type and name.  It's a bit inconvenient for my intention, but it gets the data where I can work with it.